# Loop of List into a Tabbed New List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, enumeration

I am a high school student. By observing the inputted sequence, I want to create a program that creates general formulas on quadratic to a polynomial with nth power equations. This posted code will function as a means of validation for inputted sequences. If you have a better code, please help me. Thank You!

The same concept was shown below,
[image]

here is my code

```
def shrink(numbers):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i+1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers)
          if i < len(numbers)-1]
    n2 = [x[1]-x[0] for x in n1]
    print(n2)
    if(len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2)
        return n

#shrink([1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216])
a = input()
b = a.split()
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = int(b[i])
shrink(b)

"""
The output will be:
[7, 19, 37, 61, 91]
[12, 18, 24, 30]
[6, 6, 6]
[0, 0]
[0]
"""

 #I want the output from the top to be like this!

d = [
    [7, 19, 37, 61, 91],
    [12, 18, 24, 30],
    [6, 6, 6],
    [0, 0],
    [0]
    ]

if d[2][0] == d[2][1]:
    print('cubic sequence')
```

Answer (score 0):

During the first call you initialize a list variable which you update and pass to the recursive call

```py
def shrink(numbers,return_list = []):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i+1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i < len(numbers)-1]
    n2 = [x[1]-x[0] for x in n1]

    return_list.append(n2)
    
    if(len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2,return_list)
    else:
        return return_list

print(shrink([1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]))
```

If you want the values of n1 as well :

```py
def shrink(numbers,n1_list = [], n2_list = []):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i+1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i < len(numbers)-1]
    n2 = [x[1]-x[0] for x in n1]
    n1_list.append(n1)
    n2_list.append(n2)
    # print(n2)
    
    if(len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2,n1_list,n2_list)
    else:
        return n1_list,n2_list

print(shrink([1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You **Atharva **Gundawar****.

If you want the list to be inputted, this is the answer:
Take note that input list should be separated by space and not by a comma.
Sample input: 1 8 27 64 125 216

```
def shrink(numbers, return_list=[]):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i + 1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i < len(numbers) - 1]
    n2 = [x[1] - x[0] for x in n1]

    return_list.append(n2)

    if (len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2, return_list)
    else:
        return return_list

a = input()
b = a.split()
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i] = int(b[i])
c = shrink(b)
print(shrink(b))
print(c[2][0])
print(c[2][1])
if c[2][0] == c[2][1]:
    print('cubic sequence')
```

**Input:**

1 8 27 64 125 216

**Output:**

[[7, 19, 37, 61, 91], [12, 18, 24, 30], [6, 6, 6], [0, 0], [0], [7, 19, 37, 61, 91], [12, 18, 24, 30], [6, 6, 6], [0, 0], [0]]

6

6

cubic sequence

Answer (score 0):

**This is the correct answer to eradicate the loop:**

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70423499/revisions

```
def shrink(numbers, return_list=[]):
    n1 = [(x, numbers[i + 1]) for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if i < len(numbers) - 1]
    n2 = [x[1] - x[0] for x in n1]

    return_list.append(n2)

    if (len(n2) > 1):
        return shrink(n2, return_list)
    else:
        return return_list

input_user = input("Enter data:")
b = input_user.split()
for num in range(len(b)):
    b[num] = int(b[num])
c = shrink(b)
print(c)
```